# What camera parameters should I set to detect laser dot using Android Camera

Tags: android, image-processing

I am making Android app to track laser dot.

I am simply populating array having RGB values. and then looking for brightest pixel.

I am using following camera parameters:

```
 parameters.setPreviewSize(320, 240);
 parameters.setPreviewFrameRate(10);
 parameters.setSceneMode(Camera.Parameters.SCENE_MODE_FIREWORKS);
 parameters.setFocusMode(Camera.Parameters.FOCUS_MODE_AUTO);
```

Results are fine when laser dot is at a smaller distance from camera. but having a laser dot too far or near a light source is creating problem.

Is there a better solution.?

Should I use OpenCV library?

Answer (score 1):

For best results, change your criteria; instead of looking for brightest pixels, try to find the 'reddest' pixel. Assuming the laser dot emits red light.
You can get the red value of the pixel by;

```
Color.red(pixel);
```

or

```
pixel<<8;
pixel>>>24;
```

**EDIT**

White and bright lights will still have great red values. To increase the filtering one can put a threshold values for green and blue. When these values of pixel exceeds threshold value you you may skip them, since they are likely to be white whether than pure red.

Comment: I was doing this before: but camera filter make laser dot appear white (maybe just in my fone). So i used fireworks scene mode so it just barely see laser dot and nothing else

Comment: I was doing this before: but due to camera's filters laser dot appears white not red in viewfinder.

Comment: Well, that's all I can do. I would say recognize the shape but bright stuff will most likely to have a circular pattern on cameras anyway.